# Angular route provider not working

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, angularjs-routing

I have MVC application with angular. Iam using route provider that is working fine on debug mode but when Im setting my app on iis it's not working, the site url should be: server/applicationName/#/Routeprovider
But actually the url is: server/applicationName#/Routeprovider
Only if I'm adding / to the url it's working... Anyone had this problem before?

Here is my code:

```
$routeprovider.
when("/", {
   templateUrl: "Statics/NewUser.html"
}).
when("/Admin", {
   templateUrl: "Statics/Admin.html"
});
```

Comment: did you try to set the baseUrl attribute for the main HTML page in the header ?

Comment: I did and it didn't work. But iam not sure how it's working

Comment: have you tried the html5 mode, to remove the hash.

Comment: can you get the URL in the HTML that changes the URL ?

Comment: With html5mode it didn't work. But it worked with baseUrl. Thank you :)

Comment: I will move the comment to the answer section, can you please mark it as a correct answer.. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ngRoute not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756280/ngroute-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to use the baseURL attribute in the main HTML page

Answer (score 0):

try it now ...

```
  $routeprovider.
when("/", {
   templateUrl: "/Statics/NewUser.html"
}).
when("/Admin", {
   templateUrl: "/Statics/Admin.html"
})
```